# With trigge move a row from one table where trigger exists to another table IN MYSQL

Tags: mysql, triggers

i have four table 1) **Order** 2)**Order_log**  3) **Transection** 4)**Transection_log**

When a Transection is complete and will update all the information, i want to move a row from **Order** table to **Order_log** and from **Transection** table move a row to **Transection_log**.

```
i am getting error 
Error Code: 1442. Can't update table 'transaktion' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.
```

I understand the problem but can not find any solution. Please can anyone help me;;**beställning** = Order , **beställning_log** = Order_log, **transaktion_log** = Transection_log, **transaktion** = Transection

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` TRIGGER `TabortBeställning` AFTER UPDATE ON `transaktion` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
if  (select Betalning_Metod_ID from transaktion where new.Beställning_ID = Beställning_ID ) is not null And
    (select Levererad_Datum from transaktion where new.Beställning_ID = Beställning_ID ) And 
    (select Status_ID from transaktion where new.Beställning_ID = Beställning_ID ) = 3
 then 
     Insert Into beställning_log Select * From beställning Where Beställning_ID = New.Beställning_ID;
     Delete From beställning  Where Beställning_ID = New.Beställning_ID;
     Insert Into transaktion_log Select * From transaktion Where Beställning_ID = New.Beställning_ID;
    
 else 
    SIGNAL sqlstate '99999'
    SET message_text = "Du har inte angett alla kolumn värden. Fyll på [Levererad Datum, Metod ID, Status ID ]";

  END IF;

END
```

Comment: Please show us the trigger code, the schema for all the tables involved

Comment: For described action you need a trigger defined on some fifth table. But there is no such table... Move your logic from query+trigger to stored procedure.

Comment: If i create fifth table how can i connect to fire the trigger?? Any idea?  -Ankina

Comment: I have added my trigger code. -RiggsFolly